# Case insensitive matching for pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and a row select function.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[5,6,7]})
def select_f(row):
    return row['a']
```

The question is I don't want to change the columns name(keep uppercase) and make the following function run

```
for _, row in df.iterrows:
    if select_f(row) >2:
        print row['B']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `df.filter` with a regex:

```
In [246]: df.filter(regex=re.compile('^a$', re.I))
Out[246]: 
   A
0  1
1  2
2  3
```

For your purpose, you'd use:

```
def select_f(row):
    return row.filter(regex=re.compile('^a$', re.I)).iloc[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, while not really work, I would like to return the last row. Your code still print all of row

Comment: @KEXINWANG You have to pass the row to the function.

Comment: this work for me:

    def select_f(row):
        return row.filter(regex=re.compile('^a$', re.I)).values[0]

Thanks for the help